# jQuery window load at specific point

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

```
$(window).load(...
```

waits for EVERYTHING on in the window to load. Which is great. But recently I have very much desired for an event to fire at a specific point in the page's load. For example, 'everything BUT images'.

I wish I could list my failed attempts, but I don't know where to begin or even if such a thing is possible.

Something like:

```
$(window).partialLoad({
    exclude : 'jpg, png, gif'
}, function(){
    //do something when page has fully loaded except for images
});
```

or conversely

```
$(window).partailLoad({
    waitFor : 'woff, eot'
}, function(){
    //do something after all woff and eot files have loaded
});
```

If its possible I will write a nice plugin to handle it. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption that `$(window).load()` waits for *all linked resources to download*, we could write your own, assuming that without images, that would be `iframe[src]`, `script[src]`, `link[rel="stylesheet"]` etc.

```
var items = $('iframe[src], link[rel="stylesheet"], script[src]'),
    itemsLength = items.length;

items.load(function() {
    --itemsLength;

    if ( ! itemsLength) {
        // All loaded!
    }

});
```

Comment: I thought about this. The problem is that not all link resources appear in elements. For example background images or font files appear in external css. Also not all elements fire an onload event or even a jQuery load event.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Sounds like you want the opposite of my `waitForImages()` plugin.

Comment: btw. I am an occasional reader of your blog, and have taken advantage of some of your javascript. Its an honor to receive an answer from you.

Comment: I've used `waitForImages()` what I want is not so much the opposite, its control, and regardless of file type.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Thanks! Control would be a great thing in `waitForImages()`, but then it probably should have a different name.

Comment: how about `$.fn.kickass-browser-cant-tell-me-how-to-handling-loading-anymore` If you look above, the plugin I was going to attempt would allow for exclusions or inclusions of any particular file type. Atm I am only interested in load from the window, as where `waitForImages()` allows an element to be targeted. The choice of window or an element would certainly make it cooler.

Comment: @Fresheyeball You can use `window` as the selector for `waitForImages()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9434/discussion-between-fresheyeball-and-alex)